# how do you take a website off of the internet?

Tags: vs-web-site-project

how do you take a website off of the internet? i have been tasked by my local golf club to remove there old website but im not sure how to do it.
i know the ip address but i dont know where to start to take the site down.

Comment: You must have the access to their HTTP server. They should already gave you. You should know what server softwere they are using, and you can open its config files and remove the configuration of the website.

Comment: they haven't gave me the HTTP server. is there anyway i could find it out?

Comment: They should be giving you that, at least a password. Else you won't be able to do what they wanted.

Comment: okay thank you, i will have to contact them to get all the relevant information.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's web hosting administration, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions:

Probably the quickest and easiest is to change your dns. You will need to know the dns provider so you can change the address it points to.

If you don't want to do that, find the ftp address and password and delete all the files. My ftp client of choice is https://filezilla-project.org/ . I'd take a local copy first in case they want it back. The address might be ftp.[mysite.tld] depending on the hosting.

If you are really stuck talk to the hosting provider. You can get some info about the hosting from a whois lookup on the ip address: https://who.is/